# Как правильно синхронизировать потоки в данном случае? С++

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Предположим есть функция, которая симулирует клик мышки. Время клика регулируется аргументом. При этом клик происходит в отдельном потоке, чтобы главный поток на время клика продолжал работать:

```
Mouse::Click(std::chrono::milliseconds)
{
    namespace thr = std::this_thread;
    std::thread mouseClickThread{[](){/* .... */}};
    mouseClickThread.detach();
}
```

Однако такой код может привести к тому, что пока кнопка мыши опущена и ждет указанное время, в основном потоке может снова быть вызвана функция `Click()` и тогда запустится ещё один поток с кликанием, что неправильно.

Как правильно синхронизировать потоки и нужно ли тут использовать мьютексы? Если да, то как? Я пока слаб в многопоточности, поэтому не понимаю, как это нужно использовать. `join()` - не вариант, я не хочу останавливать основной поток

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPD**:

Вариант 1 - довольно простой, но с точки зрения архитектуры к нему могут быть вопросы.
И кода вопроса передаваемых в новый поток или из него, выгоднее выглядит использовать связку `std::future<T> mouseFuture + std::async`. Как-то так:

```
/// mouse.cpp 

std::future<void> myFuture;

Mouse::Click(std::chrono::milliseconds)
{
    // При первом запуске функции myFuture.valid() будет false. Просто объявили myFuture
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/valid
    if(!myFuture.valid()) {
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        // std::launch имеет 2 вариант запуска выбираете удобный 
        // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch
        // Параметр запуска std::launch::async гарантирует асинхронность работать
        myFuture = std::async(std::launch::async, []() {
            /// Some beautiful magic here ///
        });
    }
}
```

При вызове функции `Click()` до конца выполнения задачи `valid() == true` и запуска еще одного не будет.

Можно попробовать обернуть как-то так для удобства( **пример на коленке** ). Если доулучшить вполне годное решение можно получить для такого рода задач.

```
template<typename T>
struct FutureWrapper{
    bool isReady() const { return future.valid(); }
    T get()  { return future.get();}
    std::future<T> future;
};

template<typename T>
class AsyncCaller {
public:
    template<typename Callback, typename ... Args>
    FutureWrapper<T>& callAsyncOnce(Callback&& callback, Args&& ... args) {
        if(!m_currentFuture.isReady())
            m_currentFuture.future = std::async(std::launch::async,
                                                std::forward<Callback>(callback),
                                                        std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return m_currentFuture;
    }
private:
     FutureWrapper<T> m_currentFuture;
};

/// Mouse.cpp
Mouse::Click(std::chrono::milliseconds ms) {
   /// AsyncCaller<T> asyncCaller; хранить где-то выше.
   auto& futureTask = asyncCaller.callAsyncOnce([](){
       /// ... ///
   });
   /// что-то делать с futureTask 
}
```

Comment: Нет, вы в корне неправильно поняли вопрос. Перечитайте его ещё раз.

Comment: @ComeInRage а можете, как-то пожалуйста, дополнительно описать или псевдо код написать что вы хотите на выходе.

Comment: Я вам и там всё описал и предоставил код. Что не понятно? Есть функция, которая вызывается в отдельном потоке. Как не допустить её повторного вызова, пока поток выполняется? Точнее какой способ наиболее правильный?

Comment: @ComeInRage я в своём ответе в варианте вам предложил вариант, только использовать не std::thread, а std::async + future, с запуском std::launch::async, что так же сделает задачу не основном потоке, и с помощью метода valid() позволит защититься от повторных срабатываний пока работа не будет выполнена.

Comment: У Скотта Мейерса есть хорошая глава за std::async , почитатайте 7.1 и 7.2 пункты главы 7. https://coollib.net/b.usr/Skott_Meyers_Effektivnyiy_i_sovremennyiy_C%2B%2B.pdf. Думаю так вам будет понятнее что я вам предлагаю

Comment: Прочитал. У Майерса хорошо объясняется async, потому что документацию я, оказывается, понял неправильно. Спасибо за вариант решения проблемы. Изменю оценку, если отредактируете как-нибудь ответ. Иначе сайт не позволяет

Comment: @ComeInRage отредактировал, хотел добавить про гарантированность, но вы уже прочитали. Так же добавил вариант, как обернуть использование для переиспользования, но как и написал в ответе, вариант "На коленке", если на что еще обратить внимание.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Хотя и предстоит еще разобраться с этим

Answer (score 1):

Непосредственно для избежания двойной обработки клика вам не требуется никаких хитростей кроме булевой переменной (точнее, атомарной булевой переменной, ведь вы будете работать с ней из разных потоков):

```cpp
std::atomic<bool> click_processing; // эта переменная не может быть локальной!

// …

if (click_processing.load()) return;
click_processing.store(true);
std::thread mouseClickThread{[&click_processing](){
  /* … */
  click_processing.store(false);
}};
mouseClickThread.detach();
```

Ну и про обработку ошибок не забудьте.

---

Однако, игнорировать клики пользователя просто так - не лучшая идея, по-хорошему вам надо заблокировать соответствующие кнопки на время асинхронной операции. Как это делать - зависит от используемой вами библиотеки.

А если вы их блокируете - надо будет и разблокировать обратно, для чего понадобится по окончанию работы потока "вернуться" в поток UI. Как это сделать - тоже зависит целиком от библиотеки, к примеру в случае WinAPI это будет вызов PostMessage с сообщением WM_USER. Если вы пойдёте по этому пути - то и синхронизировать вам будет ничего не надо, передача сообщения и будет механизмом синхронизации:

```cpp
bool click_processing; // эта переменная не может быть локальной!

// …

if (click_processing) return;
click_processing = true;
// тут блокируем (disable) кнопку

std::thread mouseClickThread{[&click_processing](){
  /* … */
  
  invoke_on_ui_thread_somehow([&click_processing]() {
    click_processing = false;
    // тут разблокируем (enable) кнопку
  });
}};
mouseClickThread.detach();
```

---

Ах да, последнее уточнение: создавать по потоку на каждый клик - ужасное решение, потоки дорогие. Поищите библиотеку для пула потоков, или воспользуйтесь системным пулом если вы пишете под винду.

Готовых решений на чистом с++ нет, если вы выбрали этот язык - страдайте!

Comment: Эмуляция клика не равно обработке клика пользователя. Это совершенно разные вещи :) Ваш ответ не совсем подходит, но я учту такой вариант решения проблемы